# How to parse numbers in strings?

Tags: r

At first glance, I have a simple problem. I have a column with measurements that partly consist of one area. I.e:

```
a <- c("28", "", "5.6", "12-24")
```

Now I want to convert all values. I have chosen the following approach:

```
res <- ifelse(str_detect(a, "-"), 
                     yes = paste(
                         as.character(as.double(unlist(str_extract_all(a, "[0-9.]+"))[1]) * 10),
                         "-",
                         as.character(as.double(unlist(str_extract_all(a, "[0-9.]+"))[2]) * 10)),
                     no = a)
```

The result looks like:

```
res
[1] "28"       ""         "5.6"      "280 - 56"
```

The expected output is the following:

```
res
[1] "28"       ""         "5.6"      "120 - 240"
```

Can someone explain to me why this is happening and what a correct approach can be?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @user2974951:  I have adjusted my question accordingly

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string on `"-"` and based on the output length apply different conditions  :

```
a <- c("28", "", "5.6", "12-24")

sapply(strsplit(a, '-'), function(x) 
 if(length(x) > 1) paste0(as.numeric(x) * 10, collapse = ' - ') else toString(x))

#[1] "28"        ""          "5.6"       "120 - 240"
```

---

The reason your code does not work is because `ifelse` passes all the values to both `yes` and `no` part of the code and not only those values that satisfy the condition. So when you do

```
unlist(str_extract_all(a, "[0-9.]+"))[1]
#[1] "28"
```

it is actually returning output of 1st value in `a` (28) and not 12 (from 12-24) as you were expecting.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to seperate the numbers in two columns I suggest the following from `tidyr`:

```
  a <- data.frame( Numbers = c("28", "", "5.6", "12-24"))
  b <- a  %>% tidyr::separate(Numbers,  c("A", "B"), sep = "([-])")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `ifelse` like below

```
ifelse(
  grepl("-", a),
  paste0(as.numeric(strsplit(a, "-")[[grep("-", a)]]) * 10, collapse = "-"),
  a
)
```

or `replace`

```
replace(
  a,
  grep("-", a),
  paste0(as.numeric(strsplit(a, "-")[[grep("-", a)]]) * 10, collapse = "-")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the assigned position `[1]` and `[2]`

If you use `[3]` `[4]`
then it works.

```
res <- ifelse(str_detect(a, "-"), 
              yes = paste(
                as.character(as.double(unlist(str_extract_all(a, "[0-9.]+"))[3]) * 10),
                "-",
                as.character(as.double(unlist(str_extract_all(a, "[0-9.]+"))[4]) * 10)),
              no = a)
```

Output:

```
> res
[1] "28"        ""          "5.6"       "120 - 240"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
gsubfn::gsubfn("(\\d+)-(\\d+)",~paste(as.numeric(.x)*10,as.numeric(.y)*10,sep=" - "),a)
[1] "28"        ""          "5.6"       "120 - 240"
```

Answer (score 1):

purrr style

```
map_chr(str_split(a, "-"), ~ifelse(length(.x)>1, paste(as.numeric(.x)*10, collapse = "-"), .x))

[1] "28"      ""        "5.6"     "120-240"
```