# transform a string that contains positive/negative numbers with decimals into numeric in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have the following vector:

```
x = c("=-1000.51$^{*}$", "=.0038374", "=-2.91823e-09", "=7.290392e-09","=2.254938e-08$^{**}$")
```

what is the fastest way to get transform this vector in a numeric vector like:

```
x = c(-1000.51, .0038374, -2.91823e-09,7.290392e-09,2.254938e-08)
```

using R?

I tried

```
x %>% str_match_all("[0-9]+") %>% unlist %>% as.numeric
```

but it doesn't work as I hoped. Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: `readr::parse_number(x)`

Comment: `as.numeric(gsub("[^-+0-9.e]", "", x))`

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67158041/how-to-parse-numbers-in-strings

Comment: `stringr::str_match_all(x, "[-+0-9.e]+") |> lapply(as.numeric) |> unlist()` is closer to your code attempt. Your regex pattern needed to be augmented to accommodate the exponentiation (`e-08`), negatives (leading `-`), and decimals (`.`).

Comment: Hi @r2evans. this seems to be the fastest among all. I'll give you credit if you answer it formally

Comment: The purported duplicate is not a duplicate because it has pure numbers and this one has other junk too.  Am voting to reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few one-liners. The last three are taken from the comments. Note that edge cases may behave differently for different solutions. For example, the first two allow digits within the junk but the third one does not (however that does not occur in the question example so it may not matter).  The fourth one assumes that the junk at the end starts with $ (which is always the case in the question example).

```
as.numeric(trimws(trimws(x, "left", "="), "right", "\\D"))

x |> trimws("left", "=") |> trimws("right", "\\D") |> as.numeric()

as.numeric(trimws(x, "both", "[^-0-9]"))

read.table(text = sub("=", "", x), comment.char = "$")[[1]]

library(gsubfn)
strapply(x, "-?\\d.*\\d", as.numeric, simplify = TRUE)

library(readr)
parse_number(x)

as.numeric(gsub("[^-+0-9.e]", "", x))

library(stringr)
str_match_all(x, "[-+0-9.e]+") |> unlist() |> as.numeric()
```

Comment: I didn't find a dupe with this many uses of other than `stringr`, `readr::parse_number`, or `gsub`, I wonder if this could become a good answer for future "parse number from string" questions (since it happens enough). Do you think it would be useful to add some of the traditional methods (e.g., from my comments, likely others) to fill this out as a laundry list of methods?

Comment: OK. Have added them.